# How to filter data from Pandas Data frame Dynamically?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have 3 different Dataframes with different columns as below .

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"Name": ['A', 'B', 'C'], "Age": [1, 2, 3]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Addr": ['D', 'E', 'F'], "PIN": [4, 5, 6]})

df3 = pd.DataFrame({"State": ['X', 'Y', 'Z'],"Phone": [7, 8, 9]})
```

I will pass two parameters Dataframe_Name, Column_Name .

Based on the above two parameters it will filter and print the data for corresponding Dataframe and Column  .

How to Achieve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need this:

```
In [3566]: def filter_df(df, col):
      ...:     return df[col]
      ...: 

In [3567]: filter_df(df2, 'Addr')
Out[3567]: 
0    D
1    E
2    F
Name: Addr, dtype: object

In [3568]: filter_df(df1, 'Name')
Out[3568]: 
0    A
1    B
2    C
Name: Name, dtype: object
```